# Laravel: Get the ID of User::create and insert new row using that ID

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have `AuthController` in Laravel and I have 2 tables, one is `Users` and one is `Users_Information` and I want to insert into `Users_Information` upon registration.

So I want to get the id from the following method and insert a new row and set the column ID of that row to the ID of the user I have just created.

```
     /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'username' => $data['username'] . ' ' . $data['username2'],
            'mail' => $data['mail'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
```

I want to insert into `Users_Information` with a column `id`, `current_food` and `current_level`

I have a controller for the `Users_Information` called `UserInformation`, would I just call `UserInformation::create` but how would I get the id from the `User::create`?

Answer (score 83):

Try to use `->id` of returned object, something like:

```
$id = $this->create($data)->id;
```

Comment: @TheGod39 Please, set this answer as accepted so users can quickly see the right answer.

Comment: Use $insert = Model::create([]);
$insert->id

Answer (score 50):

The `create()` method returns the model.

```
$user = User::create([
    'username' => $data['username'] . ' ' . $data['username2'],
    'mail' => $data['mail'],
    'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
]);

$userInfo = UserInformation::create([
    'user_id' => $user->id,
    'current_food' => $food,
    'current_level' => $level,
]);
```

Comment: The create() method returns the model---this helped

Comment: Working for me in Laravel 6 for the  Auth/RegisterController.php native file of Laravel , Thanks !

Answer (score 12):

use insertGetId(); it gives you the id of an inserted row.

```
$userId = User::insertGetId([
    'name' => $request->input('name'),
     'email' => $request->input('email'),
     'password' => bcrypt($request->input('password')),
]);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#inserts

Answer (score 11):

Suppose, I have a model name **Employee** and I want to insert some data in this model also want to get table id. So I can achieve this easily by below code:

```
 $employee = new Employee();
 $employee->employeeName = 'Something';
 $employee->save();
 $employee->id;
```

Answer (score 8):

Eloquent has a nice way to handle [saving relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#inserting-related-models), which can be used in your case. It allows you to save a related model without accessing the model directly. Of course you must make sure your relationship is defined in the appropriate models first.

Below will create the user and their information. I assumed the method of your relationship was called `information` but you can adjust as needed.

```
$user = User::create([
    'username' => $data['username'] . ' ' . $data['username2'],
    'mail' => $data['mail'],
    'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
])->information()->create([
    'current_food' => $current_food,
    'current_level' => $current_level
]);
```

Notice that we did not explicitly set `user_id` because we simply created the information by accessing the relationship you have defined; Laravel/Eloquent handles that for you!

Answer (score 6):

Also, if you are not using Eloquent, you can use `insertGetId`:

```
$id = DB::table('users')->insertGetId(
    [ 'name' => 'John Doe', 'email' => 'john@example.com']
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that if you set your table with an custom ID, you must indicate so in the code. In my case, my table "Antecedentes" has the custom id "ant_id" so "id" did not work and had to put "ant_id" like this:

```
$success = Antecedentes::create($data)->ant_id;
```

And i could go on.