# How can I fix this error related to to controller?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8

I have a problem, thank you for your help.
I want this to be done in the Store method when a person submits a question
But it gives me an error that says: thread_id required       ???!

```
  Subscribe::query()->create([
        'thread_id'=>$thread->id,
        'user_id' => auth()->user()->id
    ]);
```

This is the code for my Store method, which includes the subscribe model:

```
 public function store(Request $request,Thread $thread)
{
    $request->validate([
        'title' => ['required', 'min:3'],
        'description' => ['required'],
        'channel_id' => ['required'],
        'thread_id' => ['required']
    ]);

    Thread::create([
        'title' => $request->title,
        'description' => $request->description,
        'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
        'channel_id' => $request->channel_id,
    ]);

    Subscribe::query()->create([
        'thread_id' => $thread->id,
        'user_id' => auth()->user()->id
    ]);
    return redirect('/');
}
```

This is also the code related to View

```
<form action="{{route('threads.store')}}" method="post">
@csrf
<input type="hidden" name="thread_id" value="{{$thread->id}}">

<div class=" container-fluid w-75 border border-secondary rounded shadow">
    <div style="font-weight: bolder; font-size: large;" class=" my-3">فرم ارسال پرسش</div>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">

        </div>
        <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" placeholder="موضوع" aria-label="Username" value="{{old('title')}}"
               aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
    </div>
    
    <div class="input-group">
        <textarea name="description" class="form-control" aria-label="With textarea" placeholder="متن پرسش"
                  style="height: 200px;">{{old('description')}}</textarea>
    </div>


    <div class="input-group mt-3 " style="direction: ltr;">
        <select name="channel_id" class="custom-select" id="channel_id" >
            <option selected disabled value="{{old('channel_id')}}">انتخاب عنوان</option>
            @foreach(\App\Models\Channel::all() as $channel)
                <option value="{{$channel->id}}">{{$channel->name}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>

    </div>

    <div class="my-3" style="width: 100px;">
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">ارسال</button>
    </div>


</div>
```

the problem about this code on view

```
<input type="hidden" name="thread_id" value="{{$thread->id}}">
```

also i sent the Thread model on view

```
 public function create(Thread $thread)
{
    return view('answer-question.thread.thread-create',compact('thread'));
}
```

this is subcribe database
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKu1d.png)

Comment: It sounds like your validation is failing, bcs there is no `thread_id` in your form.  Looking at your form, that would mean `$thread->id` is not set. But looking at your code, it looks like you're trying to *create* a new thread, so obviously there would not be a thread ID yet ...

Comment: As far as I can see, if you're not building the url to automatically create the ``$thread`` object, consider changing it from ``'thread_id' => $thread->id,`` to ``'thread_id' => $request->thread_id,``, since is more likely the request has that property.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Thanks for your guidance so what should I do to make thread_id in subscribe   ?

Comment: [From the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models): "*Alternatively, you may use the create method to "save" a new model using a single PHP statement. The inserted model instance will be returned to you by the create method*". So `$thread = Thread::create([..`, and then `$thread->id` will give you the new ID.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel: Get the ID of User::create and insert new row using that ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37075148/laravel-get-the-id-of-usercreate-and-insert-new-row-using-that-id)

Answer (score 0):

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'title' => ['required', 'min:3'],
        'description' => ['required'],
        'channel_id' => ['required'],
        'thread_id' => ['required']
    ]);

    $thread = Thread::create([
        'title' => $request->title,
        'description' => $request->description,
        'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
        'channel_id' => $request->channel_id,
    ]);

    Subscribe::query()->create([
        'thread_id' => $thread->id,
        'user_id' => auth()->user()->id
    ]);
    return redirect('/');
}
```

you cant take store function to thread model when you save it it will come then you need to define thread end then you can call it.

Comment: thats usefull for me  but i want to send thread_id in the view beause it is required for subscribe model

Comment: you can send with return? what is the wrong

Answer (score -1):

when you send it in form body laravel don't detect it as a route param. you can use this.

```php
 Subscribe::query()->create([
        'thread_id'=>$request->thread_id,
        'user_id' => auth()->user()->id
    ]);
```

Comment: it is not come from request thread_id

Comment: @sohan thanks    when i do that i give this error:                                         SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'thread_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `subscribes` (`thread_id`, `user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, 3, 2021-11-09 14:29:55, 2021-11-09 14:29:55))